# Does the "time played" progress while the device is closed?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, zelda-link-between-worlds

After completing the game the first time with 100%, I wanted to make the hero mode "more challenging" by trying to finish with a good time played in the end and restricting myself to fulfil only the basic needs of my little green hero.

As I play mostly while commuting, can someone tell me if the game internal counter for "time played" continues while the console is closed? With "time played" I don't refer to the console's counter but the game's internal counter.

I own a 3DS XL if that makes a difference and in most cases I press pause before I close the console. I have the option for finding street pass shadow links enabled, while the device is closed.

On another note, does "pause" really pause the "time played" counter of the game?

Comment: I doubt pausing the game would pause the time played counter. Closing the lid should pause the timer as it puts the DS into "sleep" mode

Comment: That's what I thought as well initially but when googling, I found people saying both "closed device = sleep mode = no progress" and "when street pass option is enabled, progress happens" to which some others disagreed... so the public opinion seems to dissent on that topic...

Comment: @Mathias711 Thanks for the minor edits to my post. Would you be so kind as to tell my why you removed those tags? I felt they were related but I'm willing to change my mind on that.

Comment: @KADlancer Sure I want to elaborate! The [tag:3ds-xl] is only for questions about the console itself, not when you use this specific console. I doubted a bit about the [tag:achievements], but I feel that this tag is more used when getting specific achievements (/trophies), in for example Steam of Xbox Live. I see that there is a challenge in the game you want to conquer, but not a system-wide achievement. If you have any more questions, please post it on Meta (if you can, otherwise I can put it there), so other people can tell what they think about it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the game in question, but typically putting the system into sleep mode (by closing it) is not counted by other applications as played time, regardless of streetpass settings.

Comment: @Mathias711 I don't agree with the edits. The question has nothing to do with Zelda, that is just the game he is referencing. The question is related to the 3DS operating system & hardware. Which means the 3ds-xl tag would have been perfect. having it only tagged to zelda makes **no** sense.

Comment: @Panomosh He only asked if time progressed in that specific game, for a more challenging game. And the answer is probably 3DS wide (and that the ingame counter does not continue, as stated by originaluser), but this questions was only for this game, not for all games.